# Exception handling fail in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to Python. I am trying to handle the exception in file upload web API. But I am not able to catch. If is goes to success it shows the uploaded file.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import request,jsonify

import smtplib, os, cgi
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from werkzeug.utils  import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'upload/'
# These are the extension that we are accepting to be uploaded
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'pdf','docx','ods','xls'])

# For a given file, return whether it's an allowed type or not
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    try:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return('file uploaded successfully')
    except IOError:
        return("fail file upload")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you try catching all Exceptions to check?

Comment: `IOError` must not be the correct exception type. Replace by `Exception` first, print it and refine later. OR: let it run without try/except and refine then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to catch all exceptions:

```
try:
    raise ValueError('stuff')
except BaseException as e:
    print 'Statement:', e.args
    print 'Type:', type(e)
```

Outputs:

> Statement: ('stuff',)
>
> Type: (class 'ValueError')

This will let you see what's happening - using `BaseException` will capture ALL exception types, then you can query `e` to see what it is.  You should obviously be careful capturing all exceptions, and it isn't generally considered very good practice, but it might be useful for debugging at least.  When you see what the type is you can go back and narrow it down.